# Continued fraction approximation to a function and its derivative

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, approximation, continued-fractions

I am recently working on fitting a model with incomplete beta function. In order to put it into my optimization algorithm, I must find out the derivatives of the incomplete beta function $B_p(x,y)$ and program it into computer.

I don't know how to do this, but I found a paper on Journal of Statistical Software:

> Boik, Robert J., and James F. Robison-Cox. "[Derivatives of the
>   incomplete beta function.](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v03/i01/paper)" Journal of Statistical Software 3.1 (1998):
>   1-20.

The method on it is amazing and perform quite well and fast. I wonder if it is possible to use the same way to approximate any "sufficiently nice" (log-)likelihood function and its derivatives directly?

May I ask:

Any good reference book / survey paper on this topic?